# Como podria optimizar mi app de react?

Tags: json, reactjs

Les comento, yo tengo una aplicacion de react que pide datos a un backend y le responde con esta misma, el problema es que son casi 8000 datos los que retorna y cada que lo hace se tarda mucho tiempo, tambien voy a necesitar esta informacion para usarla en otros componentes, lo que tenia pensado es guardalo en memoria, para no estar llamando al backend a cada rato, no se si esto se puede hacer?

la informacion vienen de la siguiente forma:

```
pieza:{
    general_inf:{
        dato:'algo',
        ...
    },
    medidas:{
        dato:'otra cosa',
        ...
    },
    colores:{
        dato:'algo',
        ...
    },
    tecnicas:{
        subdato:'otra cosa',
        ...
    }
}
```

de esta forma esta se mandan los datos, entonces lo que quiero hacer es guardarla para usarlo luego, hay algo que me sirva para guardar esta informacion?

Comment: Guárdalos en el `localStorage` y listo, o bien en el `sesionStorage`, dependiendo si quieres que los datos se mantengan o se borren al cerrar el navegador. De cualquier tienes que revisar bien lo que está ralentizando tus app, probablemente tengas algún problema con tus estados que haga que de dispare múltiples veces el renderizado.

Comment: Como podria verificar eso?, estoy usando hooks de modo que uso useEffect para cargarlo cuando inicia, esta bien o tengo que cambiarlo?

Comment: Si cargas los datos una sola vez cuando inicias la app usando useEffect pasando como segundo argumento [] no hay problemas. Asi es como debe ser. Lo que no debes es estarlos pidiendo constantemente cada vez que algo pase.

Comment: y si quiero setear bastante objetos desde el useEffect, se hace hasta el final o lo hago una vez llegue la informacion?

Comment: por lo general una api no entrega semejante cantidad de datos de una vez, si te fijas la mayoria de las api pagina los datos. Si el backend es tuyo deberias tratar de optimizarlo mas que optimizar la app

Comment: Gracias, ya me dieron una nueva idea de como estructurar todo, se los agradesco